# What direct scheduled flights exist between Alaska and Russia?

Tags: air-travel, russia, alaska

The narrowest distance between mainland Russia and mainland Alaska is approximately 90 kilometers. Some even speculate [a bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bering_Strait_crossing) could connect the two regions, creating a land link between Eurasia and the Americas. However due to the low density of the population, very few international flights exist in that area.

What scheduled flights (if any) directly connect Alaska to Russia?

Comment: Charter flights: http://www.alaska.org/advice/visit-russia-from-alaska

Answer (score 12, accepted):

None, if you're looking only at major airlines. [This](https://www.google.ca/flights/#search;f=FAI;t=r-Russia-0x453c569a896724fb%253A0x1409fdf86611f613;d=2016-06-29;r=2016-07-03;s=0;mc=m) is a map showing non-stop Russian destinations reachable from Fairbanks, Alaska. Here's [Juneau](https://www.google.ca/flights/#search;f=JNU;t=r-Russia-0x453c569a896724fb%253A0x1409fdf86611f613;d=2016-06-29;r=2016-07-03;s=0;mc=m), [Nome](https://www.google.ca/flights/#search;f=OME;t=r-Russia-0x453c569a896724fb%253A0x1409fdf86611f613;d=2016-06-29;r=2016-07-03;s=0;mc=m) and [Anchorage](https://www.google.ca/flights/#search;f=ANC;t=r-Russia-0x453c569a896724fb%253A0x1409fdf86611f613;d=2016-06-29;r=2016-07-03;s=0;mc=m).

However [Air Russia](https://airrussia.us/tickets/) operates for 8 weeks in the summer and for the fifth season this year, you can go from Anchorage to Petropavlovsk.

You can also [charter](http://www.beringair.com/charters/) a flight with Bering Air, though it requires a 3 week [advance notice](http://www.alaska.org/advice/visit-russia-from-alaska) and 2 weeks to process the request.

There's also [Yakutia Air](http://www.yakutia.aero/en/yakutsk) which has flights from Anchorage to Petropavlovsk in the summer.